# Move along Modal dont' work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move along the modal divs i have created but don't work.

Check my script for jquery:

```
 <script>
    $("#mytabs").on('click',function() {
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    </script>
```

html/Botstrap:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                <!--    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> !-->
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Authentication</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  id="myTab">
                                                <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" class="cssbuttongo">Login</span>
                                            <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" class="cssbuttongo">Register</span>
                                            </ul>
                                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="LoginTab">

......

     <div class="tab-pane" id="RegistrationTab">
```

Comment: The statement _"but don't work"_ is absolutely meaningless... What should happen? What happens instead? Any errors in the console? ([How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/))

Comment: Don't show anything using console log or not @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `tab` try `tabs`, as docs demonstrates:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs (
   { show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } }
);
```

However, I cant fully understand from docs what arguments are necessary for `tabs()`, so cant guarantee if this

```
$("#mytabs").on('click',function() {
    $(this).tabs('show')
});
```

would be enough.